# Setting a dijit/form action dynamically with a pragmatically created widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using

```
<form id="${id}myForm">

</form>
```

I would like to add to my .js file something similar to:

```
registry.byId(this.id + "myForm").set("action", "myscript.php");
```

But, this does not work when I check in chrome dev tools.

Comment: It doesn't look like that `form` is a widget, so using Dijit's registry is not going to work. Add `data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form"` to your form node. Assuming you have Dojo configured properly, that will make it a Form widget that created declaratively.

Comment: Every time I added data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" it would not display the contents of the form. I used this instead.`<form method="post" name="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

Answer (score 0):

in your case instead of trying to get object via registry - you can use dom.byId() where dom stands for "dojo/dom", i.e.:

```
require([ 'dojo/dom' ], function(dom) {
    dom.byId("yourFormId").action = 'myscript.php';
});
```